Cryptography — Top User Swag!
I come bearing good news!!!
If your name is on one of the first two pages here, you are entitled to a little care package, as a token of our appreciation for helping shape this community into what it is today! You can expect the following items to be sent your way:
A T-SHIRT!

STICKERS!

I'll be reaching out to you at some point this week (tomorrow, most likely): please try to fill out the form I'm sending you as soon as you're able to do so! You'll have two weeks to do it, after which I'll close it and start shippin' swag! The mail man should get these to you in... let's say 6 to 8 weeks, why not!
If you're not on the list, don't worry too much about it — we've got some extra swag stored we can send to you for events and such.
Thank you all for helping this community be awesome!

Awesome, now I just need an enigma machine to put the sticker on :)

How should the t-shirt size guide be interpreted? What are those numbers? Circumference in inches? Measure the body or the shirt?

"Circumference in inches?": yes. "Measure the body or the shirt?"... yes.

Yay!!! Btw: First SE, now Crypto.SE… somehow I can’t ignore the feeling you make me want to start collecting those t-shirts. ;)

very cool. what is the material(s) the shirts are made from?

@RichieFrame: The math.SE shirt I got last month was 100% cotton. I'd assume these will probably be the same.

Phew, just in time...

Anybody got the top user swag already? I'm still waiting for mine...

Not to sound impatient... which I am :P

I doubt anyone got it, @MaartenBodewes: it's only going out today :P

Got mine today. 50% polyester, but looks good.

Just got it!


Me too. To be honest, I'm a little bit disappointed with the shirt quality – the blue color looks kind of faded and uneven, as if the dye hadn't taken properly. It looked a lot better in the preview than in reality. But still, gift horses, mouths and all that. :)

Handbook of APPLIED CRYPTOGRAPHY ! Again ! =D

Got my shirt the other day. Looks great. Need to update my avatar :)
Thanks!
