Can I get the logo somewhere and is it public domain?
I was thinking about putting it on a t-shirt.
Edit: Maybe this is not appropriate here but I don't know where else to ask. Sorry.

related: https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/672/cryptography-top-user-swag :)

https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/crypto/img/apple-touch-icon.png

We don't provide a list of the logos for every single one of our sites in any accessible place. However, all of our logos are saved and loaded in an SVG format on-site, so you could easily just download the sprites file from the site and extract the logo out of it in an essentially-vectorized format.
We generally don't care if you print a shirt for your own personal use but we do not allow the use of any of our logos in commercial settings. So you may not print and sell your own shirts with our logo on them.

Thanks for the quick response. Much appreciated.

This goes well beyond Crypto.SE and practically is something for StackExchange Inc. to decide (among legal and other reasons, because they happen produce their own t-shirts).
Therefore, I herewith advise you to contact them directly with alike questions. You can do so via the dedicated contact page which offers a contact form to reach out to the SE team. Simply choose "Other" from the topic dropdown and write your message. I'm sure they'll be happy to answer your question(s).
For your convenience, I've already pinged them while pointing to this question (hoping a SE employee finds the time to post an answer here). That's the best we moderators can do from our side to help. Thanks for understanding.

The sprite atlas animoson mentioned is located at https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/crypto/img/sprites.svg
I extracted the logo part: https://gist.github.com/CodesInChaos/5710b4ad2c0012840da7134774232786
(since the text and part of the icon are white, they're invisible on white background)

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg width="308px" height="48px" viewBox="0 0 308 48" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:sketch="http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/ns">
    <!-- Generator: Sketch 3.4.2 (15855) - http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch -->
    <title>sprites</title>
    <desc>Created with Sketch.</desc>
    <defs></defs>
    <g id="logo" sketch:type="MSLayerGroup">
        <path d="M80.992,31.576 C76.864,31.576 73.568,28.6 73.568,23.8 C73.568,19.288 76.384,16.024 80.992,16.024 C83.04,16.024 84.928,16.856 86.272,18.2 L88.896,15.576 C86.88,13.528 84.096,12.28 80.992,12.28 C74.432,12.28 69.76,17.048 69.76,23.8 C69.76,30.84 74.816,35.32 80.992,35.32 C84.096,35.32 86.88,34.072 88.896,32.056 L86.272,29.4 C84.928,30.744 83.04,31.576 80.992,31.576 L80.992,31.576 L80.992,31.576 Z M108.864,35 L102.784,25.272 C104.96,24.664 107.712,23.096 107.712,19.128 C107.712,12.6 100.224,12.6 100.224,12.6 L92.768,12.6 L92.768,16.344 L96.32,21.944 L92.768,21.944 L92.768,35 L96.512,35 L96.512,25.656 L98.656,25.656 L104.48,35 L108.864,35 L108.864,35 Z M97.216,16.344 L100.224,16.344 C100.224,16.344 103.968,16.344 103.968,19.128 C103.968,21.336 101.696,21.816 100.704,21.912 L97.216,16.344 L97.216,16.344 Z M125.792,12.6 L120.096,20.6 L114.368,12.6 L109.792,12.6 L118.208,24.408 L118.208,35 L121.952,35 L121.952,24.408 L130.368,12.6 L125.792,12.6 L125.792,12.6 Z M140.416,12.6 L132.96,12.6 L132.96,16.344 L136.512,21.944 L132.96,21.944 L132.96,35 L136.704,35 L136.704,25.656 L140.416,25.656 C140.416,25.656 147.872,25.656 147.872,19.128 C147.872,12.6 140.416,12.6 140.416,12.6 L140.416,12.6 L140.416,12.6 Z M140.896,21.912 L137.408,16.344 L140.416,16.344 C140.416,16.344 144.16,16.344 144.16,19.128 C144.16,21.304 141.888,21.784 140.896,21.912 L140.896,21.912 L140.896,21.912 Z M162.848,12.6 L149.728,12.6 L149.728,16.024 L154.432,16.024 L154.432,35 L158.144,35 L158.144,16.024 L162.848,16.024 L162.848,12.6 L162.848,12.6 Z M173.568,28.92 C178.144,28.92 181.888,25.176 181.888,20.6 C181.888,16.024 178.144,12.28 173.568,12.28 C168.992,12.28 165.248,16.024 165.248,20.6 C165.248,25.176 168.992,28.92 173.568,28.92 L173.568,28.92 L173.568,28.92 Z M173.568,15.992 C176.128,15.992 178.176,18.04 178.176,20.6 C178.176,23.16 176.128,25.208 173.568,25.208 C171.008,25.208 168.96,23.16 168.96,20.6 C168.96,18.04 171.008,15.992 173.568,15.992 L173.568,15.992 L173.568,15.992 Z M180.864,31.288 L166.08,31.288 L166.08,35 L180.864,35 L180.864,31.288 L180.864,31.288 Z M198.752,22.264 L198.752,25.816 L202.496,25.816 L202.496,29.048 C201.12,30.616 199.136,31.576 196.896,31.576 C192.768,31.576 189.44,29.272 189.44,23.8 C189.44,18.904 192.768,16.024 196.896,16.024 C198.944,16.024 200.832,16.856 202.176,18.2 L204.8,15.576 C202.784,13.528 200,12.28 196.896,12.28 C190.72,12.28 185.696,17.144 185.696,23.8 C185.696,31.128 190.4,35.32 196.416,35.32 C199.072,35.32 200.96,34.68 202.784,32.984 L202.976,35.096 L206.24,35.096 L206.24,22.264 L198.752,22.264 L198.752,22.264 Z M227.232,35 L221.152,25.272 C223.328,24.664 226.08,23.096 226.08,19.128 C226.08,12.6 218.592,12.6 218.592,12.6 L211.136,12.6 L211.136,16.344 L214.688,21.944 L211.136,21.944 L211.136,35 L214.88,35 L214.88,25.656 L217.024,25.656 L222.848,35 L227.232,35 L227.232,35 Z M215.584,16.344 L218.592,16.344 C218.592,16.344 222.336,16.344 222.336,19.128 C222.336,21.336 220.064,21.816 219.072,21.912 L215.584,16.344 L215.584,16.344 Z M242.016,35 L246.048,35 L237.088,11.96 L228.16,35 L232.192,35 L233.152,32.408 L241.024,32.408 L242.016,35 L242.016,35 Z M237.088,21.4 L239.808,29.176 L234.368,29.176 L237.088,21.4 L237.088,21.4 Z M256.032,12.6 L248.576,12.6 L248.576,16.344 L252.128,21.944 L248.576,21.944 L248.576,35 L252.32,35 L252.32,25.656 L256.032,25.656 C256.032,25.656 263.488,25.656 263.488,19.128 C263.488,12.6 256.032,12.6 256.032,12.6 L256.032,12.6 L256.032,12.6 Z M256.512,21.912 L253.024,16.344 L256.032,16.344 C256.032,16.344 259.776,16.344 259.776,19.128 C259.776,21.304 257.504,21.784 256.512,21.912 L256.512,21.912 L256.512,21.912 Z M280.352,12.6 L280.352,21.88 L271.04,21.88 L271.04,12.6 L267.296,12.6 L267.296,35 L271.04,35 L271.04,25.656 L280.352,25.656 L280.352,35 L284.096,35 L284.096,12.6 L280.352,12.6 L280.352,12.6 Z M302.656,12.6 L296.96,20.6 L291.232,12.6 L286.656,12.6 L295.072,24.408 L295.072,35 L298.816,35 L298.816,24.408 L307.232,12.6 L302.656,12.6 L302.656,12.6 Z" id="CRYPTOGRAPHY" fill="#FFFFFF" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup"></path>
        <g id="Group" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup">
            <g id="Rectangle-189-+-Rectangle-183">
                <path d="M0,0 L48,0 L48,48 L0,48 L0,0 L0,0 Z M9,9 L39,9 L39,39 L9,39 L9,9 L9,9 Z M39,15 L48,15 L48,33 L39,33 L39,15 L39,15 Z" id="Rectangle-189" fill="#FFFFFF"></path>
                <path d="M33,20 L48,20 L48,28 L33,28 L33,33 L15,33 L15,15 L33,15 L33,20 L33,20 Z" id="Rectangle-183" fill="#2980FF"></path>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>


Summary: Yes. Yes. 

True, it says "site design / logo © 2017 Stack Exchange Inc; user contributions licensed under cc by-sa 3.0 with attribution required" at the bottom of the page.   
But more relevant perhaps is whether the logo is in fact copyright-able - does it meet the legal threshold of originality?  I looks to me like: It only consists of simple geometric shapes and stylized text. It does not meet the threshold of originality needed for copyright protection, and is therefore in the public domain. It's comparable to the non-copyright-able Best Western logo; see here, here and here for more information.  
The first part of your question is answered by CodesInChaos: 

The sprite atlas animoson mentioned is located at
  https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/crypto/img/sprites.svg
I extracted the logo part:
  https://gist.github.com/CodesInChaos/5710b4ad2c0012840da7134774232786


On the bottom of every page it says that the site design and logo are copyrighted by Stacked change Inc.  So you would likely have to get permission first. 

But it also says user contributions are "under cc by-sa 3.0 with attribution required". It is not clear to me which parts of an SX site are provided by users/community and which by the company.

I'm pretty sure that user content means questions, answers, tag wikis etc. You might have more luck asking on https://meta.stackexchange.com.
